# Angular 6 - Embed applications from the workspace

Tags: angular, angular-cli-v6

I have some Microservices that each exposes UI application. These micro-frontends are a full angular 6 applications that each contains its own pages/components/services and routs.

I also have several products applications (also Angular 6) that I would like to embed these micro-frontends inside.

I want that the main product will be able to rout to a page inside the micro-frontend as it was part of the main product.

I cannot use any solution that contains an Iframe.

Is it possible to achieve this using Angular 6 workspace?